# What is __methodName__(self) method? Is it private method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods

```
class Test:
     def __init__(self,top,bottom):
         self.num = top
         self.den = bottom

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.num)+"/"+str(self.den)
```

What is the use of this `__str__(self)`? 
why do we use `__methodname__()` in python? Is there any specific use?

Comment: Method names prefixed and suffixed with a double-underscore are reserved for use by Python, and typically are used as hooks for customizing object behavior. They aren't really private, but they aren't meant to be called explicitly.

Comment: See the [Descriptive: Naming Styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) section of [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) about ' "magic" objects or attributes'.

Answer (score 1):

Some good reading for you:

- [Python Special Methods in General](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__add__#special-method-names)
- [The __str__ function specifically](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__add__#object.__str__)

tl/dr: the functions that start and end with double underscores are special functions which are automatically called as part of class behavior.  For example, when an object should be coerced into a string, the `__str__()` function is called.  For an object to support coercion to string, it must implement this function.